# Can we defer the loading of MU-Plugins in a Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Im using the WordPress Multisite MU-Plugins directory to run some custom functions which i need to be
available to ALL subsites in my network. When i run the function in the primary sites' functions.php
file it runs as expected but it obviously cannot access any subsites.

Is the problem with the loading order that WP utilises - i read [here](https://salferrarello.com/functions-plugin-mu-plugin-wordpress/) the order is:

- the WordPress core code
- mu-plugins
- plugins
- functions.php
- the theme code for the specific template being displayed

I believe the issue may be that im trying to call wp funcs that are not yet loaded yet. Is there a way to defer the loading of 'Must-Use' -plugins until, say when functions.php runs??

Answer (score 0):

You can't defer the load, no, but you can move the code in the mu-plugin that requires on other things to be loaded into action hooks for actions that are triggered later in the load order:

- hook [plugins_loaded](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/) to run code after all plugins have loaded
- hook [after_setup_theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/) to run code after the theme has loaded
  (I guess that's what you mean by 'functions.php' ?)

However I think all of WordPress's own functions are loaded before mu-plugins are loaded, so this may not be your problem.

Comment: yes i suspected as such, im just trying to send an email to myself (the super-admin) whenever media is uploaded by any subsite user. So, im using wp core funcs like: **get_user_by()**, **get_current_blog_id()** and of course **wp_mail()**. I'm using an action to hook into the **add_attachment** function